# Los paquetes nugets no se me instalan en mi solución, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Muy buenas con toda la comunidad, el otro día estaba descargando un proyecto de MAHAPPS hecho por una comunidad de programadores para mostrar todas las características de dicha framework, me lo baje de github y pues al descargarlo y abrirlo obviamente tenia que instalar todos lo paquetes que la aplicación utilizaba,tuve varios problemas pero logre instalar la mayoría en un 90% pero ahora me faltan 3 para que la aplicación pueda compilar correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que sucede es que no se me actualizan y consolidan correctamente y me dan este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los dos siguientes paquetes el error es similar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con este problema, se lo agradecería de corazón, incluso probé borrrando la cache y el problema sigue..

---

@Pikoh asi me sale al buscar en la solución........

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error parece indicar que estás haciendo referencia a una version anterior de los paquetes en tu solución. Yo intentaría quitar la referencia al paquete en la solución y dejar que nuget instale y agrege la referencia

Comment: Pikoh, como puedo hacer eso, me lo podrías mostrar por favor?

Comment: Mira a ver si en tu solucion, en algun proyecto, hay alguna referencia a materialdesigncolors. Si es asi, quítala y vuelve a probar a instalar el paquete nuget

Comment: @Pikoh Me sale en dependencia y paquetes materialdesigncolors

Comment: Mahapps no esta para core.. salvo que lo hayan cambiado ayer (lo use por ultima vez hace un mes y no era compatible con net.core)

Comment: de paso, por favor, mira el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Comment: mmmm osea que no esta hecho en core? ahi tambien esta NETframework, tambien me sale este error al ejecutar el programa:  System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Se produjo una excepción al establecer la propiedad 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source'.' (número de línea: '12'; posición de línea: '18').'

Comment: Mahapps tiene un canal de chat dentro de git donde quienes lo hacen solucionan problemas.. y tira muchos warning que no son errores reales...

Comment: ahi lo volvi a abrir, y me retracto, ahora si anda en .core... chequearia con ellos a ver si lo que bajaste es estable...

Comment: @gbianchi que lo descargaste bro, versión algo... porfa

Answer (score 0):

saludos.

Hace un tiempo escribí un programa utilizando la misma tecnología (WPF) y me encontré con el mismo problema que estás presentando, siendo la solución, al menos en mi caso, bastante sencilla; para ello todo lo que hace falta es agregar algunas líneas de código en varios archivos.

[image: Sin descripción]

Lo primero que debes hacer es ir al archivo App.xaml ubicado en tu proyecto WPF agregar las siguientes etiquetas con las direcciones de los paquetes que instalaste.

[image: Sin descripción]

Lo segundo será agregar una referencia dentro de las propiedades ubicadas en la cabecera del archivo xaml de cada ventana como se muestra subrayado en azul.